# showing update notification of web page in c#

Tags: c#, .net

iam developing  desktop application using c# dot net .iam using c# webbrowser to show web page .In this browser iam showing web page which display rss feed .but  now i want notification when ever there is  new feed ... how should i do this .

Answer (score 0):

when direct your webbrowser component to pull list of items from web page, also get items at backend and cache them (at least some information like time of publication or number of items). Next time when you do a refresh of page in component, first fetch the list and tally with cached one if there are more items or some item is more recently published than items in cache, give alert and refresh the page in webbrowser component.

Comment: thanks for reply .. can you just tell me can it possible to store web page content  in cache even if iam using dot net browser in c# window application .iam not using asp.net .

Answer (score 0):

can you temp a rss feed firstly?
then after a period of time you compare the temp one to the rss feed online

Comment: thanks for reply .....here problem is that iam just showing that web page .so from that page how can i extract feed and then compare it  with previous one ..